# using same regex both in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

**Problem:-**

I am using the following regex to find the special characters in a string

```
"/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/i"
```

I want to get all the characters that match this pattern and all that is working fine.

The **condition** is that that I have to use the same expression both in **php and javascript**.

But the `g flag` in the above regex is creating problem as **preg_match** and **preg_match_all** do not accept this flag and I have to search globally.

**Question:-**

SO how can I get all the special characters using the same expression both in php and javascript?

Comment: How are you getting the regex in both places, and why can't it be edited for JS?

Comment: The regex could be modified in php to use it in javascript. But I am asking if there is any better idea of achieving that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same regex in both PHP and JavaScript because their regex engines make different assumptions and support different features.

More than just the incompatibility with the `g` modifier, this regex will fail you if the input contains non-ASCII characters: the input encoding in PHP and JS will be almost certainly different and PHP will not even be Unicode-aware unless you use the `u` flag (which does not exist in JS because it's Unicode-aware by default).

Just use two different regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To match `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]`  in JavaScript you would have to use:

```
[\u0000-\u0008\u000F-\u001F\u0022-\u002F\u003B-\u0040\u005C-\u0060\u007C-\u0084\u0087-\u009F\u00A2-\u167F\u1682-\u180D\u1810-\u1FFF\u200C-\u2027\u202B-\u202E\u2031-\u205E\u2061-\u2FFF\u3002-\uFFFF]
```